# best way of combining the values of 2 different tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I want to add together the values of 2 tuples (of any size), and create an output tuple. 
For example:

```
a = (1,4)
b = (2,3)
```

output: `(3,7)`

Is there a better way to do it than just:

```
output = (a[0] + b[0], a[1]+b[1])
```

Comment: Please clarify if you are asking about "2 tuples" because you have tuples with 2 elements, or the "2 tuples" means you're adding a pair of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a generator expression?

```
output = tuple(a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

If you don't know that the tuples are the same length, you could try using something more fancy like `zip` (which will stop at the length of the shorter tuple), or `itertools.izip` (which will allow you to control how to handle different length tuples).

```
tuple(x+y for (x,y) in zip(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with 2-tuples, what you have is fine (and probably best).  You might consider using a different data structure, one where the `+` operator adds element-wise.  For example:

- `complex` numbers add like 2-vectors (using `.real` and `.imag` components)
- `numpy` arrays
- Write your own `Point` class, overriding the `__add__` magic method

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to do it in a way that doesn't require you spell out all elements, go with something functional:

```
output = tuple(map(sum, zip(a,b)))
```

or, a list-comp which you, again, must supply to `tuple`:

```
output = tuple([i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)])
```

you could always substitute `zip` with `zip_longest` from `itertools`, using a fill value of `0`, if the sizes might differ.

Comment: In your second example, you don't really need  the intermediate list since you can use a generator-exp instead of a list-comprehension. So you could drop the `[` `]`. i.e. `tuple(i+j for i,j in zip(a,b))`

Comment: The first example seems the best generic solution, because it works with any number of input tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple(map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b))
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
tuple(map(operator.add, a, b))
```